# Postgres composite type drop cascade removes dependant columns only

Tags: postgresql, composite-types

(Using the below sample code...) I had been puzzled to execute some (reexecutable) scripts (holding/versioning db logic in a source code repo) saying that a clearly defined column `foo.foo_b` did not exist although it had been successfully executed in the scripts.

Test code that show this:

```
-- foo.sql type script
drop type if exists foo cascade ;
create type foo as (
    --foo_b bar,  -- (a) not there in first script version
    foo_c char
) ;

-- bar.sql type script
drop type if exists bar cascade ;
create type bar as (
    bar_i int
) ;

-- simple sample code that may cause the strange error

select (null::foo).* ;
--select (null::foo).foo_b ;  -- (a) not there in first script version
```

executing the script with `(a)` outcommented (as is):

```
(0 rows affected)
(0 rows affected)
(0 rows affected)
(0 rows affected)
 foo_c
 -----
 -
(0 rows affected)
```

executing the script with our new `foo_b` column in use (removed comment `--` prefix from the above 2 `(a)`-marked lines):

```
(0 rows affected)
(0 rows affected)
(0 rows affected)
(0 rows affected)
 foo_c
 -----
 -
(0 rows affected)
ERROR: column "foo_b" not found in data type foo
  Position: 9
```

My original sql was different and actually caused another error of the same cause:

```
select row( null::bar, 'xxx' )

ERROR: cannot cast type record to foo
  Detail: Input has too many columns.
  Position: 7818
```

Comment: same applies to tables if `bar` is a `table` (or the implicitely created type of it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So obviously the **fix** was that the **execution logic must now execute `bar.sql` before `foo.sql`**, but the **error is quite strange and misleading** since one would not expect to have dropped the column `foo.foo_b` like this, but the dependent type `foo` should have been dropped instead.